# How to find sid's from the results of a subquery

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

```
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string);
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string);
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real);
```

My question is how to find the `sid` of a seller who costs the price of a product greater than the average (averaged over all the suppliers who supply that part) cost of that product?

Comment: What is the desired output? A result with two columns, pid and sid, for pairs (part, supplier) where the supplier's cost is greater than average for that product? In all cases, you should state the exact format of the output desired.

Comment: Please add the test data to your question.